# Bind iframe height to its content height with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, iframe, resize, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to pick up the `resize` event of a jQuery UI `sortable`, or any event that gets triggered, while **adding/removing** its elements. This should cause the `iframe` to change its size. This should be triggered on **every resize** and not only on load, any Javascript code should be in the parent page.

None of the approaches listed here solved my problem yet. When I tried to create a `resize` event listener for both the `contentWindow` and `content` the event does not get picked up.

How should this be done with jQuery? >> [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/piglin/0d3mq19u/15/)

```js
$(function() {

  //SKIP SAME ORIGIN POLICY
  $('#frame').contents().find('html body').html($('#content').html());
  $("link[type='text/css']").clone().appendTo($("#frame").contents().find("head"));
  $("style[type='text/css']").clone().appendTo($("#frame").contents().find("head"));
  $('#content').remove();

  //PREPARE INTERFACE
  $('#frame').contents().find('#sortable').sortable();
  $('#frame').contents().find('#add').click(function() {    
    $('#frame').contents().find('#sortable').append('<li>ITEM</li>');
  });
  $('#frame').contents().find('#remove').click(function() {
    $('#frame').contents().find('.sortable li:last-child').remove();
  });

  //1. SOLUTION EVENT LISTENERS - NOT WORKING
  var iframe = $('#frame').contents();
  console.log("IFRAME",iframe);
  iframe.on('resize', function() {
    console.log("iframe window resize event");
  }); 
  var iframeBody = $('#frame').contents().find('body');
  console.log("BODY",iframeBody);
  iframeBody.on('resize', function() {
    console.log("iframe body resize event");
  });
  var iframeSortable = $('#frame').contents().find('#sortable');
  console.log("SORTABLE",iframeSortable);
  iframeSortable.on('resize', function() {
    console.log("iframe sortable resize event");
  });
  
  //2. SOLUTION IFRAME RESIZER JQUERY PLUGIN - NOT WORKING
  $('#frame').contents().find('body').append('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.3/iframeResizer.contentWindow.js"></scr' + 'ipt>');
  iFrameResize({log:true});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.3/iframeResizer.js"></script>

<!--3. SOLUTION HTML ATTRIBUTES - NOT WORKING-->
<div style="margin:0px;padding:0px;overflow:hidden">
  <iframe id="frame" src="https://fiddle.jshell.net" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" style="width:100%; height: 100%; overflow:hidden" frameborder="1" scrolling="no" height="100%" width="100%" seamless="seamless"></iframe>
</div>

<div id="content">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add">Add</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remove">Remove</a>
  <ul id="sortable" class="sortable">
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most native jQuery approach would be using the jQuery iFrame resize plugin. It supports a variety of events. A script needs to be ran on both the parent page and the iframe. In my answer I highlighted how they can be both called from parent page >> [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/piglin/0d3mq19u/17/)

```js
$(function() {

  //SKIP SAME ORIGIN POLICY
  $('#frame').contents().find('html body').html($('#content').html());
  $("link[type='text/css']").clone().appendTo($("#frame").contents().find("head"));
  $("style[type='text/css']").clone().appendTo($("#frame").contents().find("head"));
  $('#content').remove();

  //PREPARE INTERFACE
  $('#frame').contents().find('#sortable').sortable();
  $('#frame').contents().find('#add').click(function() {
    $('#frame').contents().find('#sortable').append('<li>ITEM</li>');
  });
  $('#frame').contents().find('#remove').click(function() {
    $('#frame').contents().find('.sortable li:last-child').remove();
  });

  //SOLUTION - JQUERY IFRAME RESIZE PLUGIN
  var script = frame.contentWindow.document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.3/iframeResizer.contentWindow.js";
  frame.contentWindow.document.body.appendChild(script);
 iFrameResize({
    log: true
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.3/iframeResizer.js"></script>

<iframe id="frame" src="https://fiddle.jshell.net" sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts"></iframe>

<div id="content">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="add">Add</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="remove">Remove</a>
  <ul id="sortable" class="sortable">
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
    <li>ITEM</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```